# elasticsearch index name with date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I am trying to push kafka data to Elasticsearch, I am trying to mention my elasticsearch index name as:

"name-date" -- logdata-2017.01.18

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "XXX.XX.XXX.XX:9092"
    topics => ["c-data"]
  }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:9200"]
    index => "logdata-%{+yyyy.MM.dd}"
  }
}
```

But index is not getting created.

If I give any other index name without date format- for example 
`index => "metricbeat"` it works
but if I give with the configuration mentioned above it doesnt seem to work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you have your index name as follows:

```
index => "logdata-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}" <-- change the yyyy into uppercase
```

Comment: You sure that the index is not being created, due to the change you made in the `index` property?

Comment: Yes, right. If I give some other index name other than the date format, it is displaying in localhost:9200/_cat/indices